# Subtract two lists of tuples from each other

Tags: python, list, tuples, subtraction

I have the these two lists and I need to subtract one from the other but the regular "-" won't work, neither will .intersection or XOR (^).

```
A = [(0, 1)]
B = [(0, 0), (0,1), (0, 2)]
```

Essentially what I want is:

```
B - A = [(0, 0), (0, 2)]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use list comprehension to solve this problem:

```
[item for item in B if item not in A]
```

More discussion can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428536/python-list-subtraction-operation)

Answer (score 2):

If there are no duplicate tuples in `B` and `A`, might be better to keep them as sets, and use the [`difference`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.difference) of sets:

```
A = [(0, 1)]
B = [(0, 0), (0,1), (0, 2)]
diff = set(B) - set(A) # or set(B).difference(A)
print(diff)
# {(0, 0), (0, 2)}
```

You could perform other operations like find the [`intersection`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.intersection) between both sets:

```
>>> set(B) & set(A)
{(0, 1)}
```

Or even take their [`symmetric_difference`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.symmetric_difference):

```
>>> set(B) ^ set(A)
{(0, 0), (0, 2)}
```

Comment: When using methods like `.difference` you don't explicitly need to convert `A` to a set as it'll take any iterable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do such operations by converting the lists to sets. Set difference:

```
r = set(B)-set(A)
```

Convert to list if necessary: list(r)

Working on sets is efficient compared to running "in" operations on lists: [using lists vs sets for list differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25294897/why-is-converting-a-list-to-a-set-faster-than-using-just-list-to-compute-a-list)